# how to install cvxopt on windows 7 64 bit machine for python 3.5 of anaconda?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning, svm, cvxopt

Please suggest step by step method to install cvxopt on Windows7 64 bit machine for python version 3.5. I'm really facing hard time to install it.
[image]

Above is the error i'm getting.

After doing : conda install -c omnia cvxopt=1.1.8 on cmd,I am getting below error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you tried something like `pip install cvxopt` which will resolve to compile from sources which is sometimes kind of trouble on windows depending on your setup (compilers, build-tools, ...).

As you are already using Anaconda i recommend using builds of [others](https://anaconda.org/omnia/cvxopt).

```
conda install -c omnia cvxopt=1.1.8
```

The link suggests that it's the most recent version and supporting win64.

Comment: Please check updated question,I tried what you told,it gave other error.